# Developer console not working of YouTube Data API v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

### Credentials page not working of YouTube Data API v3.

1. I accessed `https://console.developers.google.com` and show Dashboard page.
2. I inputed `YouTube Data` to filter and selected `YouTube Data API v3`.
3. Show API & Service of YouTube page.
4. Clicked `Credentials` of sidebar.
5. `Failed to load.` I and other everytime.

### error message

```
Failed to load.
There was an error while loading /apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/credentials?project={{my-project-id}}. Please try again.
```

Similar problems occur with `console.cloud.google.com`.
When I contacted GCP support, I was introduced to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Have you solved this problem by now? I'm facing the same problem at the moment.